# How to use nsmallest between a range in my dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a list of prices for every hour of the year. I need to get the nsmallest prices every 24 hours.

I have the following code but I can only use it for one day

```
for j in range(0,len(Winter_Data.index)+1):
    if ((j+1) % 24)==0:
        Qreheat= Winter_Data.loc[i:j,'Qflex'].sum()
        Heat_units = Qreheat/HP_heat_capacity
        hours = Qreheat/Heat_units
        Winter_Data.loc[Winter_Data.nsmallest(int(hours),'Pbill').index, 'Qreheat'] = Heat_units
        i=i+24
        print(Winter_Data['Qreheat'])
```

The dataframe should look like this:
[image]

I want to set for instance 10 in the column Qreheat in the 2 nsmallest values of Pbill. The thing is that lets say I have two days. when I call nsmallest it takes the 2 nsmallest values of the whole column, but I only want the nsmallest of the last 24 rows.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your dataframe: `Winter_Data.head(10).to_dict()` and your expected output.

Comment: What does this mean "Basically, my problem is that I need to do operations intraday when I have an hourly dataframe."???

Comment: what is your time column name?